# I have problems with array_multisort in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-multisort

I try to order an array for multi values (first points, then golaverage, then dif and finally gf, I have this code:

```
foreach ($clasificaciones as $clave => $fila) {
                $puntos[$clave] = $fila['puntos'];
                $golaverage[$clave] = $fila['golaverage'];
                $dif[$clave] = $fila['dif'];
                $gf[$clave] = $fila['gf'];
            }


            array_multisort($puntos, SORT_DESC, $golaverage, SORT_DESC, $dif, SORT_DESC, $gf, SORT_DESC, $clasificaciones);
```

The array before to order with array_multisort is this:

```
array(2) {
  ["Sevilla"]=>
  array(16) {
    ["jugados"]=>
    int(38)
    ["ganados"]=>
    int(17)
    ["empatados"]=>
    int(8)
    ["perdidos"]=>
    int(13)
    ["gf"]=>
    int(62)
    ["gc"]=>
    int(47)
    ["dif"]=>
    int(15)
    ["pinchazos"]=>
    int(21)
    ["puntos"]=>
    int(59)
    ["imagen"]=>
    string(15) "Sevilla, Espana"
    ["racha1"]=>
    string(103) "racha"
    ["racha2"]=>
    string(116) "racha"
    ["racha3"]=>
    string(101) "racha"
    ["racha4"]=>
    string(100) "racha"
    ["racha5"]=>
    string(99) "racha"
    ["golaverage"]=>
    int(-5)
  }
  ["Getafe"]=>
  array(16) {
    ["jugados"]=>
    int(38)
    ["ganados"]=>
    int(15)
    ["empatados"]=>
    int(14)
    ["perdidos"]=>
    int(9)
    ["gf"]=>
    int(48)
    ["gc"]=>
    int(35)
    ["dif"]=>
    int(13)
    ["pinchazos"]=>
    int(23)
    ["puntos"]=>
    int(59)
    ["imagen"]=>
    string(14) "Getafe, Espana"
    ["racha1"]=>
    string(107) "racha"
    ["racha2"]=>
    string(102) "racha"
    ["racha3"]=>
    string(100) "racha"
    ["racha4"]=>
    string(106) "racha"
    ["racha5"]=>
    string(108) "racha"
    ["golaverage"]=>
    int(6005)
  }
```

with var_export:

```
'Sevilla' => 
  array (
    'jugados' => 38,
    'ganados' => 17,
    'empatados' => 8,
    'perdidos' => 13,
    'gf' => 62,
    'gc' => 47,
    'dif' => 15,
    'pinchazos' => 21,
    'puntos' => 59,
    'imagen' => 'Sevilla, Espana',
    'racha1' => 'racha',
    'racha2' => 'racha',
    'racha3' => 'racha',
    'racha4' => 'racha',
    'racha5' => 'racha',
    'golaverage' => -5,
  ),
  'Getafe' => 
  array (
    'jugados' => 38,
    'ganados' => 15,
    'empatados' => 14,
    'perdidos' => 9,
    'gf' => 48,
    'gc' => 35,
    'dif' => 13,
    'pinchazos' => 23,
    'puntos' => 59,
    'imagen' => 'Getafe, Espana',
    'racha1' => 'racha',
    'racha2' => 'racha',
    'racha3' => 'racha',
    'racha4' => 'racha',
    'racha5' => 'racha',
    'golaverage' => 6005,
  )
```

The problem is that after array_multisort the order of array is the same... why? Sevilla have -5, and Getafe 6005.. Probably is a very stupid thing but I don't see it

Comment: Can you post a `var_export` instead of `var_dump`?

Comment: It's working here https://3v4l.org/XjQlH Getafe comes before Sevilla.

Comment: doesn't work for me... Please wait, I put the complete array...

Comment: Try pasting in the link I posted.

Comment: Everything works perfectly on your link, but on my website it doesn't ... I think the problem is another ... I'm still investigating